# Android service not starting, no idea why

Tags: android, service

I'm trying to run a thread by starting it with a service, but it won't start. It won't even log.

This is my inner service class. The service class creates a new background thread and starts it.
The backgroundthread and the service class are both innerclasses so they can reach the variables.

```
public class MyService extends Service {
    private BackgroundThread background;
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");
        background = new BackgroundThread();        
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy");
    }


    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        super.onStartCommand(intent, startId, startId);
        Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.d(TAG, "onStart");
        background.start();
        return startId;
    }
}
```

I'm starting the service in the MainActivity by this:

```
startService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
```

And this is my manifest:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >


    <activity
        android:name="com.example.antioversleepapp.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.antioversleepapp.SettingsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_settings" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.antioversleepapp.InfoActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_info" >
    </activity>
    <service android:enabled="true" android:name="com.example.antioversleepapp.MyService" />
</application>
```

Please help me out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This is my inner service class

That is not possible. It either needs to be a static inner class (in which case, your `<service>` element also needs changing) or it needs to be a separate public class.

> The backgroundthread and the service class are both innerclasses so they can reach the variables.

I do not see any "variables" that your service needs to "reach". Moreover, it is impossible for Android to create an instance of an inner class, since it does not have an instance of the outer class.

Comment: I need the backgroundthread to run in the background and do calculations, which are provided by the mainactivity. And need to send them back. I need the service to keep the backgroundthread running. Maybe you can help me out in an other way?

Comment: @RobinDijkhof: "I need the service to keep the backgroundthread running" -- only if you plan on that thread running when you do not have an activity. If the thread is only needed while the activity exists, you do not need a service.

Comment: Thanks for that, do you know how to keep my mainActivity active in the background?

Comment: @RobinDijkhof: *You* don't keep "my mainActivity active in the background". The user does, by navigating your app, or pressing HOME. Your activity is "active" until it is destroyed (`finish()` or BACK button press) or your entire process is terminated.

Comment: Sorry that was not what i meant. I'm trying to keep my app active in the background. To prevent it from being killed by the os.

Answer (score 0):

try this code in your start service button, I hope it works :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Service.class);

MainActivity.this.startService(intent);
```